# Is this Spring block thread safe?

Tags: java, spring

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class); 

....

 ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<Data>> dataFuture = asyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, Data.class);
 dataFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<Data>>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
          log.error("Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<Data> dataResponseEntity) {
          Data data = dataResponseEntity.getBody();
          List<Event> event = data.getData();
          for (Event ent: event) {
              System.out.println(String.format("[%s] %s", new Timestamp(date.getTime()), ent.toString()));
              insertEventToDB(eventCollection, ent);
          }
      }
  });
```

I am calling an API and on success callbacks, I am inserting the data to the database. The question I am concerned with is either this `onSuccess` block is thread safe or not? How can I improve it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't more concerned that the database inserts are transactional?

Comment: @M. Deinum don't know, that's why I asked the question

Comment: @AngerClown what if I make a `ArrayList` and replace it insert function, will it be thread safe?

Comment: There are too many things unknown to answer your question like is the `dataResponseEntity` immutable, what is the `eventCollection` and who can access it and also if `insertEventDB` is thread safe, what happens during `insertEventToDB` and whether the insert into the DB is transactional / atomic.